# AWS node Instance can't be accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-cdh

I found problem with my EC2 instance. The errors messages are like this picture bellow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmdva.png)

Anybody know why could that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Network interface is not up. Try the below inside your host to check if network interface is up

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

If not try this and again try the above command

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

Let me know if you have any issues.